# Problem when using window.scrollBy / window.scrollTo

Tags: html, typescript

So I have this code where I'm calling a function on html:

```
<!-- Here I have the bar with the sections names -->

    <!-- Componente 'app-sections' que muestra las secciones del menú -->
    <app-sections (sectionSelected)="capturarEvento($event)" [sections]="menu.menuSections"
        [section_selected]="sectionSelected">
    


<!-- Here I show the title of the section and the content of each one -->
<div *ngFor="let menuSections of menu.menuSections" class="pt-3 dark:bg-slate-400">
    <div [id]="menuSections.name">
        <div class="pl-4 text-base font-medium pt-4">
            {{menuSections.name}}
        </div>
        <!-- This shows the content of the section -->
        <div>
            <app-product (product_added)="addProduct($event)" [sectionSelected]="menuSections" 
                [products]="updated_products" [menuLocal]="menuLocal">
            </app-product>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The part where I'm having the problem (I think) is this one:

<app-sections (sectionSelected)="capturarEvento($event)" [sections]="menu.menuSections"
[section_selected]="sectionSelected">
</app-sections>

This goes to a different .ts file where I made this function:

goToSection(section: MenuSection) {
this.sectionSelected.emit(section);

```
const selectedSection = document.getElementById(section.name);
if (selectedSection) {
  selectedSection.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
}
```

}

And the .ts file has this html file associated:

```
<div *ngFor="let section of sections"(click)="goToSection(section)" class="snap-start snap-center mr-3 px-3 py-2 rounded-full text-base text-center font-medium w-full transition-all border" [ngClass]="{'bg-amber-200 dark:bg-amber-400 text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200': section_selected==section, 'bg-white dark:bg-gray-500  dark:text-gray-200': section_selected!=section}">
        <p>
            {{section.name}}
        </p>
</div>
```

The idea is that there is a bar where there are several sections of the page, each time I click on a section the window scrolls automatically to said section using goToSection (no problems there!). The problem is that the bar blocks the section title and a piece of the content of the section. I have tried using scrollBy/scrollTo with a displacement on the Y axis of a number of pixels equal to the size of the  bar, but when I use those to methods, the scrollIntoView no longer works.

Can anybody think of a different way to aproach this maybe? Thank you very muchs.